# csv reader only reads one record

Tags: c#, file, csv

At the moment, I am using Lumenworks CsvReader to read in a csv file by row using the following code:

```
string[,] table = new string[67,250];
int i = 0;
int r = 0;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try {
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName),true))
        {
             int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

             while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < fieldCount; j++)
                 {
                     table[j, i] = csv[j];
                 }
                 i++;
             }
         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     }
}
```

The issue is that it will read both the header names and the first record but exits the while loop immediately after without reading anymore records into the table. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the raw CSV data here? I mean, CSV-formatted text data.

Comment: Remove the empty catch and tell us the error. An empty catch is the perfect way to hide bugs for yourself but not for the user.

Comment: potential Index out of bound cause by `i` which is never reset in your loops or `j` if you have more lines than 67 which is max of the table

Comment: `table[j, i] = csv[j];` is the cause of your problem.

Comment: The table needed to have a width of 68, not 67. Thanks for the help.